# Little clarification needed with regards to closures in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am going through the mozilla docs about closures and I wondering why the following code would not work. Could someone clarify on why the following wouldn't work whereas defining a variable and calling it works.

```
var outerFunction = function(inp) {
    var input = inp;
    var innerFunction = function() {
         console.log(inp);
    };
    return innerFunction;
};

outerFunction(32); //returns nothing
```

vs

```
var outerFunction = function(inp) {
    var input = inp;
    var innerFunction = function() {
         console.log(inp);
    };
    return innerFunction;
};

 var newFunc =    outerFunction(32);
 newFunc();    // returns 32
```

Thanks, and sorry if this is a stupid question.

Comment: Side note, in both cases the variable `input` is declared and has a value assigned, but the variable is never used.

Comment: It's not clear what it is you don't understand. Your second example is clearly different from the first, and it's different in exactly the way it should be in order to get the value logged to the console.

Comment: For your first one, `outerFunction(32)()` worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second code executes the function you are getting as a return object for the first function (note that your function returns a function that needs to be called in order to execute). You can make the returning function self invoking, then it's going to work without assigning it to another variable:

```js
 var outerFunction = function(inp) {
    var input = inp;
    var innerFunction = function() {
         console.log(inp);
   };
   return innerFunction;
};

(outerFunction(32)()) //returns 32
```

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense now. I was calling a function but never actually invoking it.

Answer (score 1):

`outerFunction` returns a function, however in your first example, that function is never called.

```
function createFunction(num) {
  return function() {
    alert(num);
  }
}

// Created a new function, without calling it
var myFunction = createFunction(32); 

// Call that function
myFunction();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first snippet of code doesn't return nothing, it returns a [Function object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function), or the same thing that you're assigning to `newFunc` in the second snippet:

```
var outerFunction = function(inp) {
    var input = inp;
    var innerFunction = function() {
         console.log(inp);
   };
   return innerFunction;
};

console.dir(outerFunction(32));
```

[image]

You need to invoke that returned function using parentheses if you wish to return its value, just like how you invoke `newFunc()` in the second snippet:

```
(outerFunction(32)());
// 32
```

Comment: So what I was doing was I console logging the function instead of returning the value of the function, am I correct ? @rink.attendant.6

Comment: You were just running a function that created a function which you did nothing to. I added to `console.dir` call to show the output of the function that was ran.

Comment: Thanks, that's what i meant. Sorry for the poor explaination on my end

Answer (score 0):

The `return innerFunction;` instruction returns a function object (an instance of the `innerFunction` function), not its execution. That's why you need to "instantiate" it with

```
var newFunc = outerFunction(32);
```

and then executes it with

```
newFunc();
```

`outerFunction` is like a function factory: it creates a function that must be executed to get a result.